# Google Script Sharing Rights

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I came across Google Script. Went through their API and looked through some of their tutorials. The first tutorial makes a script to create a document and fires an email off. If I add other people to that email list, they won't be able to view it right away. They have to request permission to see it even though I sent them the link.

Is there a way to have this coded in the script to give rights to the people that are being emailed the link to view and edit?

Also, going through the API and emailing people, they show that cc and bcc can be used. The API example doesn't show how to do that. Here is what I have been looking through: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/defaultservices

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to have this coded in the script to give rights to the people that are being emailed the link to view and edit?

[`Document.addEditor()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#addEditor%28String%29), [`Document.addEditors()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#addEditors%28String%29), [`Document.addViewer()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#addViewer%28String%29) and [`Document.addViewers()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#addViewers%28String%29) let you assign permissions to others.

> Also, going through the API and emailing people, they show that cc and bcc can be used.

Look at [`MailApp.sendMail(recipient, subject, body, options)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail%28String,String,String,Object%29), for a description of the "advanced parameters" that make up `options`. The options object may include both `cc` and `bcc` members.